# Creating dropdownlist from values in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I have a table called `Roles` with three fields

1. `Guid RoleId`
2. `string RoleName`
3. `string Description`

In my `register.cshtml` view I want to have a `dropdownlist` which shows the list of RoleName from `Roles` table. I also need to be able to get that value and work with it, like assigning the Role to user, which will in done in controller.
My view currently looks like the one below, i'm using model as `AspNetUser` but it doesn't have knowledge about `Role` which is what I want to show in `dropdownlist.`

```
@model Sorama.CustomAuthentiaction.Models.AspNetUser
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Register";
    Layout = "~/Views/shared/_BootstrapLayout.empty.cshtml";
}

@section Styles{
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
}
<div class ="form-signin">

    @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account"))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading"> Register </h2>
        <div class ="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Email, new{@placeholder = "Email"})</div>
        <div class ="input-block-level">@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.UserName, new{@placeholder = "UserName"})</div>
        <div class ="input-block-level">@Html.PasswordFor(model=>model.Password, new{@placeholder ="Password"})</div>
        <div class ="input-block-level">@Html.DropDownListFor(//don't know what to do

        <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    }
</div>
```

My controller looks like this

```
   public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //private readonly IDbContext dbContext;
        //
        // GET: /Account/
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
        {
            if(Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Register()
        {
            string [] roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();
            return View(roles);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(AspNetUser model)
        {

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

    }
```

What do I need to do, to have that dropdownlist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller you need to pass the `string[]` (`IEnumerable<string>`) representing your roles into your view somehow...

There are many ways to achieve this, but in your AccountController you ***could*** do the following:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
   private IDbContext dbContext;

   public AccountController(IDbContext dbContext)
   {
       // Made up field that defines your GetAllRoles method
       this.dbContext = dbContext;
   }

   public ActionResult Register()
   {
      // Call the GetAllRoles() and capture the result in a variable called roles
      var roles = dbContext.GetAllRoles();

      return View(new AspNetUser {
         Roles = roles
      });
   }
}
```

*Note: I do not enforce the list to be in any form in the controller (I do not specify it should be a select list), I may want to display the items as in a different way and I let the view be flexible by passing the values only and allowing the view to decide how to render the values.*

In your View you can then use where you want the dropdown list to appear:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Roles, Model.Roles
    .Select(role => new SelectListItem { Text = role, Value = role })
```

As I mentioned, there are many ways to achieve what you are wanting but almost one thing is certain, that with aspnet mvc you will most likely be using the Html helper `DropDownListFor` MSDN Documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlistfor(v=vs.108).aspx

EDIT 1:

Create a model to hold the User and Role informations like so:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
   public AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<string> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

In the controller it could look like so:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
   private RoleProvider roleProvider;

   public AccountController(RoleProvider roleProvider)
   {
       this.roleProvider = roleProvider;
   }

   public ActionResult Register()
   {
      // Call the GetAllRoles() and capture the result in a variable called roles
      // var roles = roleProvider.GetAllRoles();

      // Or, as you have specified:
      var roles = Roles.GetAllRoles();

      return View(new RegisterViewModel {
         AspNetUser = GetTheAspNetUser(),
         Roles = roles
      });
   }
}
```

In the View you need to update the model to use:

```
@model Sorama.CustomAuthentiaction.Models.RegisterViewModel
```

***If you are unwilling/unable to make such a change you could add the list of Roles to the Viewbag:***

```
ViewBag.RoleList = roleProvider.GetAllRoles();
```

Or as you alluded to:

```
ViewBag.RoleList = Roles.GetAllRoles();
```

Then access in the View like so:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Roles, ViewBag.RoleList
    .Select(role => new SelectListItem { Text = role, Value = role })
```

Comment: Can you explain about that IDbContext class? Do i just need to add some namespace to use it or? I need to create a class for that?

Comment: It is a fictional interface I added it because I am unsure how you access the `GetAllRoles()` method. In the mvc projects I use I have IOC (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) wire up my controllers and provide the controllers with the dependencies they require. I envisage that you would pass in the class that holds the `GetAllRoles()` method.

Comment: Is the `GetAllRoles()` in a separate class to your controller? If it is  in the controller rather than a separate class then you do not need to pass in the argument to the constructor, but I would urge you to think about putting it into a different class if you are not already, this will help you make your application SOLID (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design))

Comment: Actually i'm using default RoleProvider to get list to roles I have. So, `Roles.GetAllRoles();` gets all the roles for me which is array of strings. But in my view i use model as `aspnetuser` which doesn't have knowledge of `Roles`. so how would it work in view if i pass the roles as I have done in contoller shown above

Comment: Ok in that case see Edit 1

Answer (score 2):

In a similar scenario, I've done something like this:

```
private void BagSelectList()
{
    ViewBag.List = new SelectList(
            db.SetOfCandidateValues, 
            "KeyPropertyOfTheSet", 
            "NameOfThePropertyToAppearInTheDropDownList", 
            selectedValue);
}
```

And in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
            model => model.ForeignKeyProperty, 
            (SelectList)ViewBag.List)
```

(Of course, if you dislike the `ViewBag`, you can do it using the strongly typed view model.)