# DropdownListFor (ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I writing ASP.NET MVC web app.

I have webpage here is design of it

[Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcUJR.jpg)

Here is DropdownListFor

Also I have model , here is code:

```
 public class Companies
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }



    [Display (Name = "Компания")]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }


}
```

I need to display CompanyName in DropDownList
CompanyName 's is in table (over 10)

I try to do it like this

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Company, 
                new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Companie_s))), 
                "Select Company")
```

But this right when I have `enum` and static values.
Like this

```
public class Companies
{
    [Key]
    public int CompanyID { get; set; }



    [Display (Name = "Компания")]
    public Companie_s CompanyName { get; set; }
    public enum Companie_s
    {
        Ciklum,
        Luxoft
    }

}
```

How I need to write code in my case?

Thank's for help.

Comment: What is Companie_s ?

Comment: Edited my post@jao

Comment: Did you take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/694361/106866 ?  If that isn't working, please show us what it looks like now.

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. You want to know how to load your DropdownListFor with data from your model? If so, I don't believe it changed from version 3: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7142961/215552

Comment: Okay, I will try @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: I have one question. In this post he has

`public IEnumerable<Contrib> ContribTypeOptions = 
        new List<Contrib>
        {
            new Contrib {ContribId = 0, Value = "Payroll Deduction"},
            new Contrib {ContribId = 1, Value = "Bill Me"}
        };`

I wrote my code like this
 
       `public IEnumerable<Companies> CompaniesOption =
            new List<Companies>
            {

            };`
    But what I need to write inside list to get data with all companies in table? @MikeMcCaughan

Comment: Again, your question is confusing, and you didn't answer the question in my last comment. Are you hard-coding the list of companies in an Enum, or are you retrieving them from somewhere else?

Comment: I try to hardcode and it works. I don't understood how to retrieve it from table, and because of it I post this question.@MikeMcCaughan

Comment: Seems I found answer here [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17108572/generate-dropdownlist-from-a-table-in-database)